# how to compare two sentence and retrieve a word or several word if 2 sentence equals in java

Tags: java, string

I have an input sentence in variable String sentence and want to compare with a set of String[] sentence2 like below in java

```
String sentence = "I am fine today";
String[] sentence2= {"how are %s to day", I am %s today","thank %s for you answer"}
```

the output of this question result in true condition (match) and retrieving a word "fine".
if input changed like this: String sen =  I am happy today, the output result in true condition(match) and retrieving a word "fine"

I have a function  and using split for split the sentence into word and comparing with the array word

```
 if (similarity(sentence,sentence2)>2) {
     String a = getkata(sentence, sentence2);
    ..
    }
    public static int similarity(String a, String b) {
            int count = 0;
            String[] words = a.split(" ");
           // String[] words2=b.split(" ");
            for (int i=0; i < words.length; i++){
                if(b.contains(words[i])) {
                    System.out.println(i);
                    count=count+1;
                }

            }
            return count;
        }
public static String getkata(String a, String b){
        String hasil="";
        String[] kata = a.split(" ");
        String[] cari = b.split(" ");
        for (int i=0; i< kata.length; i++){
            if(cari[i].contains("%s")){
                hasil = kata[i];
            }
        }
        return hasil;
}
```

this code work, but I want code directly compare two sentence without split into word

Comment: Even after I tried to re-format your question to make more readable; I still have no clue what you want to achieve. Please put up a real [mcve] and explain where you are stuck; instead of just putting up requirements.

Comment: What code you tried to achieve your goal?

Comment: The word in the second example should be "happy" I guess?

Comment: i have a function to get a word like %s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can replace `%s` with `(.*?)` then you can solve 90% of your problem, you can use matches to check for example :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String sen = "I am fine today";
    String[] sen2 = {"how are (.*?) to day", "I am (.*?) today", "thank (.*?) for your answer"};
    for (String s : sen2) {
        if (sen.matches(s)) {
            System.out.print("Matche : ");
            System.out.println(sen);
        }else{
            System.out.println("Not Matche");
        }
    }
}
```

This will show you :

```
Not Matche
Matche : I am fine today
Not Matche
```

---

**Edit**

> I want an answer a boolean true and retrieve %s word

In this case you use Pattern and Matches for example :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String sen = "I am fine today";
    String[] sen2 = {"how are (.*?) to day", "I am (.*?) today", "thank (.*?) for your answer"};
    Pattern pattern;
    Matcher matcher;
    for (String s : sen2) {
        pattern = Pattern.compile(s);
        matcher = pattern.matcher(sen);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Yes found : " + matcher.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Yes found : fine
```

Comment: it was not answere that I want... I want  an answer a boolean true and retrieve %s word

Comment: @yudialcampari check my update, you can use Patterns in this cases

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
    for (String s: sen2) {
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(s.replace("%s", "(.*)"));
        Matcher matcher = pat.matcher(sen);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
    }
```

Comment: pretty close. I didn't see the update before I posted it.